# glassfish with jruby on rails: Modifing "glassfish is loading your application" page

Tags: glassfish, jruby

I'm running glassfish gem with jruby on rails. I would like to modify "glassfish is loading your application" page with our startup page. 
Is that possible for glassfish gem?

EDIT: Is that possible (and how) glassfish server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for glassfish application server, or glassfish gem? I know that it is possible with the latter.

At any rate, to do this on glassfish gem, you'd have to hack one of the jars that the gem ships. Basically, that startup page is hard coded in grizzly (I believe) somewhere, and that file resides in that jar. It's not a pretty process, and it is very brittle. For the minimal gain that you get for showing a customized page, which is shown for a very brief time, it is too much trouble to endure, in my opinion.

I'm sure this is possible with glassfish the server, and it might be similar, but I have not tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks. We are running glassfish gem now, but we do plan to move to glassfish server for production (since we have other things).